# Css book layout (horizontal accordion)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a page with a book layout, so a page with some tabs that use can expand one at a time.

Here a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/book-layout-l28gh?file=/src/App.js:0-1419

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const dataset = [
  { name: "A section", description: "page A" },
  { name: "B section", description: "page B" },
  { name: "C section with long title", description: "page C" },
  { name: "D section", description: "page D" }
];

export default function App() {
  return <Page />;
}

function Page({}) {
  const [openSection, setOpenSection] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: "100vh"
      }}
    >
      {dataset.map((datum, i) => {
        const { name } = datum;
        const isOpen = i === openSection;

        return (
          <div
            key={name}
            style={{
              height: "100%",
              backgroundColor: isOpen ? "white" : "lightgray",
              border: `1px solid ${isOpen ? "white" : "black"}`,
              padding: 10,
              flex: 1,
              flexGrow: isOpen ? 1 : 0,
              transition: "all 2s ease"
            }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                cursor: "pointer",
                writingMode: isOpen ? "horizontal-tb" : "vertical-rl",
                transition: "all 2s ease"
              }}
              onClick={() => setOpenSection(i)}
            >
              {name}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If you test it, you can notice some problems:

1. when you expand a section, the title doesn't make a smooth transition with it pass to be vertical to horizontal. It should be a smooth rotation
2. **sometimes, I didn't understand exactly when, when you click a title, all the card seems to get closer to each other.**
3. another request is make the grey area all clickable but it is obvious a problem when it is open

Why? What's the problem? It there a better approach to do a layout like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed all of your problems as you said.

**Problem #1 -> solved:**
you should use `white-space:nowrap`. if your text is large so in end of your box it will break to the next line. `white-space:nowrap` don't let that. (I don't recommend that cause this is not good for too long title text.)

**Problem #2 -> solved:** happens when you click some item and in middle of action (opening box) click on another one. this is because of `display: flex` and `flexGrow: 1`.

you used flex box and `justifyContent: "center"`. so when you click and click on another one your wrapper getting smaller and all the cards seem to get closer to each other. `flexGrow: 1` will break them.
so `flexGrow: 5` is solution.

**Problem #3 -> solved:** wrong place to set `onClick`. you should set `onClick` event on your box not on your text. and a condition for cursor is what you want. (item is selected so cursor must be `default` otherwise must be `poiner`).

**Bonus :)** if you set a small width to your wrapper so your rotate box will be prettier. it rotates at start of text and bingo.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const dataset = [
  { name: "A section" },
  { name: "B section" },
  { name: "C section with long title" },
  { name: "D section" },
  { name: "E section" },
];

function Page() {
  const [openSection, setOpenSection] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: "100vh",
      }}
    >
      {dataset.map((datum, i) => {
        const { name } = datum;
        const isOpen = i === openSection;
        return (
          <div
            key={name}
            onClick={() => setOpenSection(i)}
            style={{
              height: "100%",
              backgroundColor: isOpen ? "white" : "lightgray",
              border: `1px solid ${isOpen ? "white" : "black"}`,
              padding: "20px 30px",
              flex: 1,
              flexGrow: isOpen ? 5 : 0,
              transition: "all 1s linear",
              boxSizing: "border-box",
              cursor: openSection !== i ? 'pointer' : 'default',

              "&:first-child": {
                left: 0,
              },

              "&:last-child": {
                right: 0,
              },
            }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                transform: `rotate(${isOpen ? "0" : "90"}deg)`,
                transition: "all 1s linear",
                width: 1,
                whiteSpace: "nowrap",
              }}
            >
              {name}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **Smooth transition**: add `white-space:nowrap` so that the text wont shrink when size reduces. Make title div's position absolute so that it's width won't mess with layout and transition.
2. **click bug**: Couldn't reproduce. Sometimes the codesandbox doesn't update properly. You need to refresh the output page and test again. Check with my updated code if it happens there too.
3. **make gray area clickable**: move the mouse pointer and the click handler to parent with isOpen condition.

[Modified codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/book-layout-forked-7cfs0?file=/src/App.js):

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const dataset = [
  { name: "A section" },
  { name: "B section" },
  { name: "C section with long title" },
  { name: "D section" },
  { name: "E section" }
];

export default function App() {
  return <Page />;
}

function Page({}) {
  const [openSection, setOpenSection] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: "100vh"
      }}
    >
      {dataset.map((datum, i) => {
        const { name } = datum;
        const isOpen = i === openSection;

        return (
          <div
            key={name}
            style={{
              height: "100%",
              backgroundColor: isOpen ? "white" : "lightgray",
              border: `1px solid ${isOpen ? "white" : "black"}`,
              flex: 1,
              flexGrow: isOpen ? 1 : 0,
              transition: "all 2s ease",

              //my changes
              padding: 0,
              flexBasis: "1.2rem",
              cursor: !isOpen ? "pointer" : "auto",
              position: "relative"
            }}
            onClick={!isOpen ? () => setOpenSection(i) : null}
          >
            <div
              style={{
                transition: "all 2s ease",

                //my changes
                transform: `rotate(${isOpen ? "0" : "90"}deg) 
                translateX(${isOpen ? "0" : "50"}%)`,
                whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                width: isOpen ? "100%" : "1rem",
                position: "absolute",
                top: isOpen ? "1rem" : "0",
                left: isOpen ? "1rem" : "0",
                fontWeight: "bold"
              }}
            >
              {name}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I will follow the same order in which you introduced your problems.*

1. **[writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)** which you're using on the titles, cannot be animated. You could try rotating the text instead using the **[transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)** property
2. If you want to make the whole grey area clickable, you should move both the **onClick** function and the **cursor: "pointer"** property to the parent div of that exact element which is the title.

Comment: I don't think the solution you proposed for 2) works because in that case you will have the entire area clickable, not only the grey one. I want clickable only the area of the card when it is closed.
Thanks for the 1 point suggestion. And what about the main problem? The strange glitch described above

Comment: Sorry! my bad. Then you could use the already declared condition variable **isOpen** in the following matter:
cursor: isOpen ? "default" : "pointer",
And for the onClick function:
onClick={ isOpen ? ()=>{} : () => setOpenSection(i)}

Comment: I tried replace writing-mode with css rotate but the result is a bit strange: 
`// writingMode: isOpen ? "horizontal-tb" : "vertical-rl",
transform: `rotate(${isOpen ? "0" : "90"}deg)``

I update the codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

**try this to your code for grey part area clickable and ease in transition**

```
import { useState } from "react";

const dataset = [
  { name: "A section" },
  { name: "B section" },
  { name: "C section with long title" },
  { name: "D section" },
  { name: "E section" }
];

export default function App() {
  return <Page />;
}

function Page({}) {
  const [openSection, setOpenSection] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: "100vh"
      }}
    >
      {dataset.map((datum, i) => {
        const { name } = datum;
        const isOpen = i === openSection;

        return (
          <div
            key={name}
            style={{
              height: "100%",
              backgroundColor: isOpen ? "white" : "lightgray",
              border: `1px solid ${isOpen ? "white" : "black"}`,
              padding: 10,
              flex: 1,
              flexGrow: isOpen ? 1 : 0,
              cursor: "pointer",
              writingMode: isOpen ? "horizontal-tb" : "vertical-rl",
   transition: "all 2s ease"
            }}
          >
            <div
              style={{
               transition: "all 2s ease"
              }}
              onClick={() => setOpenSection(i)}
            >
              {name}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```